# Python MongoDB: How to add a nested dictionary to a key in an existing Document

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, nested, pymongo

I have been using Python for a while and want to learn DBs now. I am trying to learn MongoDB.

**Goal**: To add a Nested dictionary to a key in a pre existing document.

I am using Pymongo for this.

Like for ex. I have this-

```
{'name':'Ryan', 'titles':[{'title_name':'Victory Set'}]}
```

And I want to add another dictionary in `titles` key, so that it looks like this-

```
{'name':'Ryan', 'titles':[{'title_name':'Victory Set'}, {'title_name':'Bronze Trial'}]}
```

I have seen you can use `update_one` or `update_many` to update a pre existing value, but couldn't find for adding new data.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, refer https://mongoplayground.net/p/P5w6bF0UtWj

```
db.collection.update({
  "name": "Ryan"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "titles": {
      "$each": [
        {
          "title_name": "Bronze Trial"
        },
        {
          "title_name": "Silver Trial"
        }
      ],
      
    }
  }
})
```